# Get-AuthenticodeSignature from byte array seems not to work

Tags: powershell, digital-signature

For me, the Get-AuthenticodeSignature function does not seem to work with a byte array. Has anyone had similar experiences?

Sample Code:

```
$file = 'C:\Temp\foo.ps1'
$byteArray = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file)
$foo1 = Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath $file
$foo2 = Get-AuthenticodeSignature -SourcePathOrExtension $file -Content $byteArray
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Temp> $foo1.Status
Valid
PS C:\Temp> $foo2.Status
NotSigned
```

I can't understand why the same file once has the status Valid and once NotSigned.
On the Microsoft site it is also documented this way, but it does not work as it is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-authenticodesignature?view=powershell-5.1#example-4-get-the-authenticode-signature-for-a-file-content-specified-as-byte-array).

Are there any restrictions in PowerShell 5 regarding the function?

Comment: "The contents of the file must be in Unicode (UTF-16LE) format." this might be probably the reason

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @santiago-squarzon for the hint.
The content must be specified in UTF-16LE format.

```
$file = 'C:\Temp\foo.ps1'
$byteArray = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file)
$utf8String = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($byteArray)
$utf16leByteArray = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($utf8String)
$foo1 = Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath $file
$foo2 = Get-AuthenticodeSignature -SourcePathOrExtension $file -Content $utf16leByteArray
```

Comment: Please also add a brief detail on why it was failing before so future readers can see it too.

Comment: Also, you can simplify to: `Get-AuthenticodeSignature -SourcePathOrExtension ps1 -Content ([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content -Raw $file)))`